# how to render merged imodel from multiple imodels in one viewport?

Tags: imodeljs

I have merged multiple imodels in one file like below (from iModeljs test code):

```js
const mergedIModelFileName: string = "...path/combined.bim";
const mergedDb = SnapshotDb.createEmpty(mergedIModelFileName, {
  rootSubject: { name: "Merge Test" },
});
const campusSubjectId: Id64String = Subject.insert(
  mergedDb,
  IModel.rootSubjectId,
  "Campus"
);

const garageSubjectId: Id64String = Subject.insert(
  mergedDb,
  IModel.rootSubjectId,
  "Garage"
);

const buildingSubjectId: Id64String = Subject.insert(
  mergedDb,
  IModel.rootSubjectId,
  "Building"
);

mergedDb.saveChanges("Create Subject hierarchy");

if (true) {
  const campusIModelFileName = "...path/source1";
  const campusDb = SnapshotDb.openFile(campusIModelFileName);
  const transformer = new IModelTransformer(campusDb, mergedDb, {
    targetScopeElementId: campusSubjectId,
  });
  await transformer.processSchemas(new BackendRequestContext());
  transformer.context.remapElement(IModel.rootSubjectId, campusSubjectId);
  await transformer.processAll();
  transformer.dispose();
  mergedDb.saveChanges("Imported Campus");
  
  campusDb.close();
}
if (true) {
  const garageIModelFileName =
    "...path/source2";
  const garageDb = SnapshotDb.openFile(garageIModelFileName);

  const transformer = new IModelTransformer(garageDb, mergedDb, {
    targetScopeElementId: garageSubjectId,
  });
  transformer.context.remapElement(IModel.rootSubjectId, garageSubjectId);
  await transformer.processAll();
  transformer.dispose();
  mergedDb.saveChanges("Imported Garage");

  garageDb.close();
}

if (true) {
  const buildingIModelFileName =
    "...path/source3";
  const buildingDb = SnapshotDb.openFile(buildingIModelFileName);
  const transformer = new IModelTransformer(buildingDb, mergedDb, {
    targetScopeElementId: buildingSubjectId,
  });
  await transformer.processSchemas(new BackendRequestContext());
  transformer.context.remapElement(IModel.rootSubjectId, buildingSubjectId);
  await transformer.processAll();
  transformer.dispose();
  mergedDb.saveChanges("Imported Building");

  buildingDb.close();
}
mergedDb.close();
```

It gives merged imodel file. However, it gives merged imodel file with different views.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iqkq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsoKa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t8LM.png)

What I want and need is to see all of models that I merged in one viewport.
Is there a IModelTransformOptions to do so?
If it is possible, I would really appreciate if you give me some code to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with or without IModelTransformer, depending on what you want to end up with.

You can use the [`ViewCreator3D.createDefaultView`](https://www.itwinjs.org/reference/imodeljs-frontend/views/viewcreator3d/) function once you have your merged iModel to create a default view containing all the 3D models in the merged model.

If you wanted to merge the existing [`SpatialViewDefinition`](https://www.itwinjs.org/reference/imodeljs-backend/viewdefinitions/spatialviewdefinition/)s, you could create a subclass of [`IModelTransformer`](https://www.itwinjs.org/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodeltransformer/) and override [`onTransformElement`](https://www.itwinjs.org/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodeltransformer/ontransformelement/) and [`shouldExportElement`](https://www.itwinjs.org/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodeltransformer/shouldexportelement/), to form a combined view definition+model selector.